# How to simplify the following expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you express this in its simplest form? This is the answer I have to some problem, but I wish to double check if its possible to express it very simply (maybe there's some trick I'm missing).

$$\frac{(n-v+1)(n-v+2)}{2 \cdot (n+1)} + \left(\frac{n\cdot v}{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: You might reduce to the same denominator, but it would't be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique, which works here, is to put the two fractions over a common denominator.  You can do that by multiplying the second term by $2$ top and bottom.  Then you can expand the product in the first numerator and the numerator of the second will cancel one of the terms.